# Want to show specific div while click in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have three paragraphs with classname p1,p2 and p3 And three `div` with classname div1,div2 and div3. All `div` are hidden.
Now while I clicking `p1` class, only `div1` is shown and while clicking `p2` class, `div1` close and `div2` shown.

But in my code while clicking `p1` or `p2` or `p3` all div(`div1`, `div2`, `div3`) are shown.

**css**

```
.ask_btn_paragraph
{display : none;}
```

**html**

```
<p class="ask_btn"><span>&#43;</span>This is first paragraph</p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">1stHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
<p class="ask_btn"><b><span>&#43;</span>This is second paragraph</b></p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">2ndHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issndnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
<p class="ask_btn"><b><span>&#43;</span>This is third paragraph</b></p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">3rdHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issndnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
```

**script**

```
$('.ask_btn').click(function () {
        $(".ask_btn_paragraph").toggle();
 })
```

Where is the problem ? Someone Help me please....

Comment: Where are the `<div>`s

Comment: On `ask_btn` click you need to hide all `ask_btn_paragraph`, then show the paragraph below the button clicked.

Comment: @Meheer Ali.....sorry for the mistake. I have updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$(".ask_btn_paragraph")` will select each all `p` with class `.ask_btn_paragraph` and hide them. You should

- hide all the `'.ask_btn_paragraph'` using `.hide()`
- Get the next element to clicked element using `next()`
- Then then check the visiblity of element using `is(':visible')`
- And then `show()` if its hidden.

```js
$('.ask_btn').click(function(){
  let x = $(this).next();
  let hidden = !x.is(':visible')
  $('.ask_btn_paragraph').hide();
  if(hidden) x.show();
})
```

```css
.ask_btn_paragraph
{display : none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="ask_btn"><span>&#43;</span>This is first paragraph</p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">1stHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
<p class="ask_btn"><b><span>&#43;</span>This is second paragraph</b></p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">2ndHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issndnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
<p class="ask_btn"><b><span>&#43;</span>This is third paragraph</b></p>
<div class="ask_btn_paragraph">3rdHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issndnknskjnskjnHello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn Hello This issnknskjnskjn</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").hide()
$("p").on("click",function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr('id').match(/(\d+)/)[1];
    $("div").hide()
    $("#div"+attr).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id=p1>Parargraph1</p>
<div id=div1>Division 1</div>
<p id=p2>Parargraph2</p>
<div id=div2>Division 2</div>
<p id=p3>Parargraph3</p>
<div id=div3>Division 3</div>
```

Comment: OP wants toggle(); effect